# What happens to a graft if the "donor" dies?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

I've seen there are rules for grafts in case the donor "goes loud".
If the donor goes loud you loose the graft and it can have some nasty side effects. But what happens if instead he dies/is destroyed? (grafts are from the Flowers of Hell book)

Answer (score 2):

### You decide what happens.

Personally I lean towards using the rules for going loud. But this is based on the assumption, that if given a chance, most Demons will go loud to have a fighting chance or enable a faster escape.

But RAW there are no details as to what happens when [a Demon dies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53973/what-happens-when-a-demon-dies/72331#72331). So  feel free to make something up that makes sense for your story (perhaps the graft partially transforms, it starts to deteriorate, ...).

The only detail that we do "know" is the following (Flowers of Hell p160):

> A handful of demons have tried ripping pieces off of angels — or one another — to create form gadgets, but something
>   about the process doesn’t work.